# Count number of ways to pair integers 1-14 under constraint

Tags: python, math, set, combinations

Consider the following problem:

How many ways are there to split the integers 1 through 14 into 7 pairs such that in each pair, the greater number is at least 2 times the lesser number?

This is obviously a math problem, and there are several solutions to it. I wondered if there is a way to write a python program instead, to automatically search through all possible pairs, and give me the correct answer. Right now I'll take this moment to clarify: I do not want a "reasonable" solution to this problem, I want a python program to solve it (goes through all the possible pairs).

While going through the possibilities of how I might do this, I considered using a `set`, since the order of a set doesn't matter. If I had a for loop for instance, that counted all the pairs, the program would need to know when to stop counting the pairs or when it had already counted a certain pair. Since the for loop would have randomly ordered pairs, if I put those pairs into a set, it would likely make it easier to figure out if I had already counted that pair, since order does not matter in a set.

I'm kind of stuck right now...so I'm open to any suggestions on how I can build on this idea, or any other potential ideas (I don't have any code yet to show...hopefully coming soon).

UPDATE:

Resolved. It seems there are several ways to do this, and I built some code that works (using some helpful answers as well). Efficiency doesn't really matter here (since we're only pairing the numbers from 1-14), but as the number of pairs increase, it becomes more and more important to write efficient code, so that's a suggestion if you're doing something similar to this.

Comment: Have a look at the [itertools](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html) module, in particular the `pairwise`, `permutations` and `combinations` methods. This will probably get partway there, and you can apply further filters to get what you need.

Comment: python has builtin lib to work out permutations/combinations, you just need to loop thru the result to match your conditions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First we need to understand the problem. There are lots of ways to pair the numbers 1 through 14, for example:

- `(1, 2), (3, 4), (5, 6), (7, 8), (9, 10), (11, 12), (13, 14)` (one pair meets the criteria)
- `(1, 14), (2, 13), (3, 12), (4, 11), (5, 10), (6, 9), (7, 8)` (five pairs meet the criteria)
- `(1, 8), (2, 9), (3, 10), (4, 11), (5, 12), (6, 13), (7, 14)` (all pairs meet the criteria)

When coming up with these pairings by hand, I first pick a number to pair with `1`, then I pick a number to pair with `2` unless two was already paired with `1` in which case I pick a pairing for `3`. The pattern continues until all numbers have been paired.

Lets implement that recursively in python:

```py
def generate_pairings(unpicked_numbers, picked_pairs = ()):
    if not unpicked_numbers:
        # all of the numbers have been picked, and the pairs are finalized
        yield picked_pairs
        return

    # the pairing is incomplete - there are more numbers to pair up
    # go through every possible pairing and yield that
    for i in range(1, len(unpicked_numbers)):
        new_pair = (unpicked_numbers[0], unpicked_numbers[i])
        new_unpicked_numbers = unpicked_numbers[1:i] + unpicked_numbers[i+1:]

        yield from generate_pairings(new_unpicked_numbers, picked_pairs + (new_pair,))
```

Then, we implement a function to check if a certain pairing matches your criteria:

```py
def all_pairs_max_double_min(pairs):
    return all(max(pair) >= 2 * min(pair) for pair in pairs)
```

And finally, we simply loop through all of the combinations & check them individually.

```py
numbers = tuple(range(1, 15))
count = 0
for pairing in generate_pairings(numbers):
    if all_pairs_max_double_min(pairing):
        count += 1

print(f"There are {count} combinations in which all pairs' larger value is at least double the smaller value.")
```

There are **144** combinations in which all pairs' larger value is at least double the smaller value.

Comment: *"When coming up with these pairings by hand, I first pick a number to pair with 1, then I pick a number to pair with 2 unless two was already paired with 1 in which case I pick a pairing for 3. The pattern continues until all numbers have been paired."* <<< All numbers can be paired with 1, and almost all numbers can be paired with 2. Every time you pick 14 as the match for anything but 7 you explore countless dead-ends. It seems more efficient to do it the other way around: first find a number to pair with 7, then find a number of pair with 6, etc. This way you'll avoid most dead-ends.

Comment: @Stef the OP specifically mentions "I want a python program to solve it (goes through all the possible pairs)". Otherwise I wouldn't have approached it this way.

Comment: @Stef not all numbers can be paired with 1, (there is a mathematical solution to the problem), just wanted to let you know, 7 and 14 MUST be paired together (as per the solution).

Comment: @5rod Yes, that's exactly my point. It would be much more efficient to start by pairing 7, then pair 6, then pair 5, etc. But this answer does it the other way around: it starts by pairing 1, then pairs 2, etc. This is inefficient because when pairing 1 this answer tries all numbers as possible pairs for 1, including 7 and 14 and other high numbers which cannot be paired with 1 in a valid solution. So this answer enumerates through a lot of impossible attempts. It would be much more efficient to start by pairing 7 with 14, then pair 6 with 12 or 13, etc., to avoid all impossible attempts.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification @Stef, don't think the efficiency really matters with just pairing 14 numbers, but it probably would matter with run time if the numbers increased to say, 5000.

Answer (score 0):

You can start with a pool of all numbers, and then iteratively remove a legitimate pair of numbers from it in each recursive call until the pool is empty, at which point you have found a legitimate set of pairs of numbers for output. Store the output in a set of frozensets to remove duplicate sets of pairs generated in different order:

```
def get_pairs(n):
    def _get_pairs(pool):
        if not pool:
            yield frozenset()
        for i in pool:
            for i2 in pool.intersection(range(i * 2, n + 1)):
                for pairs in _get_pairs(pool - {i, i2}):
                    yield frozenset([(i, i2)]) | pairs
    return set(_get_pairs(set(range(1, n + 1))))
```

so that:

```
print(*get_pairs(14), sep='\n')
```

would output 144 frozensets of tuples:

```
frozenset({(6, 12), (3, 13), (4, 10), (5, 11), (2, 8), (1, 9), (7, 14)})
frozenset({(2, 9), (4, 10), (6, 13), (7, 14), (1, 8), (5, 12), (3, 11)})
frozenset({(6, 12), (2, 8), (7, 14), (1, 11), (4, 9), (3, 10), (5, 13)})
frozenset({(3, 8), (6, 13), (1, 11), (4, 9), (2, 10), (5, 12), (7, 14)})
frozenset({(6, 13), (5, 11), (4, 8), (3, 12), (2, 10), (1, 9), (7, 14)})
frozenset({(1, 12), (5, 10), (6, 13), (2, 8), (7, 14), (4, 9), (3, 11)})
frozenset({(1, 12), (5, 10), (6, 13), (3, 9), (2, 8), (4, 11), (7, 14)})
frozenset({(6, 12), (4, 10), (3, 9), (7, 14), (1, 8), (2, 11), (5, 13)})
frozenset({(2, 9), (6, 13), (1, 10), (4, 8), (7, 14), (5, 12), (3, 11)})
frozenset({(6, 12), (2, 9), (4, 10), (1, 13), (3, 8), (5, 11), (7, 14)})
frozenset({(1, 12), (2, 9), (5, 10), (6, 13), (4, 8), (7, 14), (3, 11)})
frozenset({(6, 12), (3, 8), (5, 11), (1, 10), (4, 9), (2, 13), (7, 14)})
frozenset({(6, 12), (3, 8), (5, 10), (4, 11), (1, 9), (2, 13), (7, 14)})
frozenset({(6, 12), (2, 9), (4, 10), (5, 13), (7, 14), (1, 8), (3, 11)})
frozenset({(6, 12), (3, 8), (7, 14), (1, 11), (4, 9), (2, 10), (5, 13)})
frozenset({(6, 13), (5, 12), (2, 8), (1, 11), (4, 9), (3, 10), (7, 14)})
frozenset({(6, 12), (2, 9), (3, 8), (1, 13), (5, 10), (4, 11), (7, 14)})
frozenset({(6, 13), (3, 9), (4, 8), (1, 11), (2, 10), (5, 12), (7, 14)})
frozenset({(6, 12), (3, 13), (5, 10), (4, 9), (1, 8), (2, 11), (7, 14)})
frozenset({(2, 9), (4, 10), (6, 13), (5, 11), (3, 12), (1, 8), (7, 14)})
frozenset({(6, 12), (5, 10), (3, 9), (4, 13), (1, 8), (2, 11), (7, 14)})
frozenset({(1, 12), (2, 9), (3, 8), (5, 10), (6, 13), (4, 11), (7, 14)})
frozenset({(6, 12), (2, 9), (1, 13), (5, 11), (4, 8), (3, 10), (7, 14)})
frozenset({(3, 8), (5, 10), (6, 13), (2, 12), (1, 11), (4, 9), (7, 14)})
frozenset({(6, 12), (3, 13), (5, 10), (2, 8), (4, 11), (1, 9), (7, 14)})
frozenset({(2, 9), (3, 8), (6, 13), (1, 10), (4, 11), (5, 12), (7, 14)})
frozenset({(6, 13), (5, 12), (4, 8), (3, 10), (2, 11), (1, 9), (7, 14)})
frozenset({(2, 9), (3, 8), (5, 10), (6, 13), (1, 11), (4, 12), (7, 14)})
frozenset({(6, 12), (3, 8), (5, 10), (1, 11), (4, 9), (2, 13), (7, 14)})
frozenset({(2, 9), (6, 13), (5, 12), (4, 11), (1, 8), (3, 10), (7, 14)})
frozenset({(6, 12), (5, 13), (7, 14), (4, 9), (2, 10), (1, 8), (3, 11)})
frozenset({(1, 12), (2, 9), (4, 10), (3, 8), (6, 13), (5, 11), (7, 14)})
frozenset({(6, 12), (5, 11), (4, 8), (3, 10), (1, 9), (2, 13), (7, 14)})
frozenset({(6, 12), (5, 10), (1, 13), (3, 9), (2, 8), (4, 11), (7, 14)})
frozenset({(6, 12), (5, 13), (4, 8), (3, 11), (2, 10), (1, 9), (7, 14)})
frozenset({(6, 12), (2, 9), (5, 10), (4, 13), (7, 14), (1, 8), (3, 11)})
frozenset({(2, 9), (5, 10), (6, 13), (7, 14), (1, 8), (4, 12), (3, 11)})
frozenset({(6, 12), (4, 10), (3, 9), (5, 11), (1, 8), (2, 13), (7, 14)})
frozenset({(3, 8), (5, 10), (6, 13), (2, 12), (4, 11), (1, 9), (7, 14)})
frozenset({(6, 12), (5, 10), (2, 8), (4, 13), (7, 14), (1, 9), (3, 11)})
frozenset({(6, 12), (4, 8), (3, 10), (7, 14), (2, 11), (1, 9), (5, 13)})
frozenset({(5, 10), (6, 13), (2, 8), (7, 14), (4, 12), (1, 9), (3, 11)})
frozenset({(6, 12), (3, 9), (5, 11), (1, 10), (4, 13), (2, 8), (7, 14)})
frozenset({(6, 12), (3, 13), (5, 10), (2, 8), (1, 11), (4, 9), (7, 14)})
frozenset({(6, 12), (3, 9), (2, 8), (1, 10), (7, 14), (4, 11), (5, 13)})
frozenset({(6, 12), (5, 11), (4, 9), (1, 8), (3, 10), (2, 13), (7, 14)})
frozenset({(5, 10), (6, 13), (2, 8), (1, 11), (4, 9), (3, 12), (7, 14)})
frozenset({(6, 12), (5, 10), (3, 9), (4, 8), (1, 11), (2, 13), (7, 14)})
frozenset({(4, 10), (6, 13), (3, 9), (1, 8), (2, 11), (5, 12), (7, 14)})
frozenset({(6, 12), (5, 10), (4, 8), (7, 14), (1, 9), (2, 13), (3, 11)})
frozenset({(1, 12), (4, 10), (6, 13), (3, 9), (5, 11), (2, 8), (7, 14)})
frozenset({(3, 8), (5, 10), (6, 13), (2, 11), (4, 12), (1, 9), (7, 14)})
frozenset({(2, 9), (6, 13), (5, 12), (4, 8), (1, 11), (3, 10), (7, 14)})
frozenset({(6, 12), (3, 9), (7, 14), (4, 11), (1, 8), (2, 10), (5, 13)})
frozenset({(2, 9), (5, 10), (6, 13), (4, 8), (1, 11), (3, 12), (7, 14)})
frozenset({(6, 12), (3, 13), (5, 10), (4, 8), (2, 11), (1, 9), (7, 14)})
frozenset({(6, 12), (2, 9), (3, 13), (5, 10), (4, 11), (1, 8), (7, 14)})
frozenset({(5, 10), (6, 13), (2, 12), (4, 8), (7, 14), (1, 9), (3, 11)})
frozenset({(5, 10), (6, 13), (4, 8), (3, 12), (2, 11), (1, 9), (7, 14)})
frozenset({(6, 13), (3, 9), (2, 12), (1, 10), (5, 11), (4, 8), (7, 14)})
frozenset({(6, 13), (5, 11), (2, 12), (4, 9), (1, 8), (3, 10), (7, 14)})
frozenset({(6, 13), (5, 12), (3, 9), (4, 11), (1, 8), (2, 10), (7, 14)})
frozenset({(6, 12), (5, 10), (3, 9), (4, 11), (1, 8), (2, 13), (7, 14)})
frozenset({(4, 10), (3, 8), (6, 13), (5, 11), (2, 12), (1, 9), (7, 14)})
frozenset({(6, 13), (5, 11), (2, 8), (3, 10), (4, 12), (1, 9), (7, 14)})
frozenset({(4, 10), (6, 13), (3, 9), (2, 8), (1, 11), (5, 12), (7, 14)})
frozenset({(6, 13), (3, 9), (5, 11), (1, 10), (2, 8), (4, 12), (7, 14)})
frozenset({(6, 12), (2, 8), (1, 10), (3, 11), (4, 9), (7, 14), (5, 13)})
frozenset({(1, 12), (2, 9), (6, 13), (5, 11), (4, 8), (3, 10), (7, 14)})
frozenset({(2, 9), (6, 13), (5, 11), (1, 8), (4, 12), (3, 10), (7, 14)})
frozenset({(5, 10), (6, 13), (3, 12), (4, 9), (1, 8), (2, 11), (7, 14)})
frozenset({(6, 13), (5, 12), (4, 9), (1, 8), (2, 11), (3, 10), (7, 14)})
frozenset({(5, 10), (6, 13), (2, 8), (3, 12), (4, 11), (1, 9), (7, 14)})
frozenset({(6, 12), (3, 13), (5, 11), (2, 8), (1, 10), (4, 9), (7, 14)})
frozenset({(5, 10), (6, 13), (3, 9), (2, 8), (1, 11), (4, 12), (7, 14)})
frozenset({(6, 12), (3, 8), (5, 11), (4, 13), (2, 10), (1, 9), (7, 14)})
frozenset({(3, 8), (6, 13), (5, 11), (2, 10), (4, 12), (1, 9), (7, 14)})
frozenset({(6, 13), (2, 8), (1, 10), (7, 14), (4, 9), (5, 12), (3, 11)})
frozenset({(6, 12), (2, 9), (3, 8), (5, 10), (4, 13), (1, 11), (7, 14)})
frozenset({(6, 12), (4, 10), (3, 9), (2, 8), (7, 14), (1, 11), (5, 13)})
frozenset({(6, 12), (2, 9), (5, 10), (1, 13), (4, 8), (7, 14), (3, 11)})
frozenset({(4, 10), (6, 13), (5, 11), (2, 8), (3, 12), (1, 9), (7, 14)})
frozenset({(6, 12), (4, 10), (3, 8), (7, 14), (2, 11), (1, 9), (5, 13)})
frozenset({(6, 12), (3, 13), (5, 11), (4, 8), (2, 10), (1, 9), (7, 14)})
frozenset({(6, 12), (5, 10), (1, 13), (2, 8), (7, 14), (4, 9), (3, 11)})
frozenset({(5, 10), (6, 13), (3, 9), (2, 12), (4, 8), (1, 11), (7, 14)})
frozenset({(6, 12), (5, 10), (7, 14), (4, 9), (1, 8), (2, 13), (3, 11)})
frozenset({(6, 12), (2, 9), (3, 8), (5, 11), (4, 13), (1, 10), (7, 14)})
frozenset({(6, 12), (2, 9), (3, 8), (1, 10), (7, 14), (4, 11), (5, 13)})
frozenset({(6, 12), (5, 11), (4, 13), (3, 10), (2, 8), (1, 9), (7, 14)})
frozenset({(6, 12), (3, 9), (1, 10), (4, 8), (7, 14), (2, 11), (5, 13)})
frozenset({(5, 10), (6, 13), (3, 9), (2, 12), (4, 11), (1, 8), (7, 14)})
frozenset({(2, 9), (6, 13), (5, 11), (1, 10), (4, 8), (3, 12), (7, 14)})
frozenset({(6, 12), (1, 13), (3, 9), (5, 11), (4, 8), (2, 10), (7, 14)})
frozenset({(6, 12), (2, 9), (5, 11), (4, 13), (1, 8), (3, 10), (7, 14)})
frozenset({(6, 12), (5, 10), (1, 13), (3, 9), (4, 8), (2, 11), (7, 14)})
frozenset({(4, 10), (3, 8), (6, 13), (5, 12), (2, 11), (1, 9), (7, 14)})
frozenset({(6, 13), (5, 11), (2, 12), (4, 8), (3, 10), (1, 9), (7, 14)})
frozenset({(6, 13), (5, 11), (2, 8), (1, 10), (3, 12), (4, 9), (7, 14)})
frozenset({(6, 12), (3, 8), (5, 10), (4, 13), (2, 11), (1, 9), (7, 14)})
frozenset({(6, 12), (3, 8), (1, 10), (7, 14), (4, 9), (2, 11), (5, 13)})
frozenset({(5, 10), (6, 13), (3, 9), (1, 8), (4, 12), (2, 11), (7, 14)})
frozenset({(1, 12), (6, 13), (5, 11), (2, 8), (4, 9), (3, 10), (7, 14)})
frozenset({(6, 13), (3, 9), (1, 10), (4, 8), (2, 11), (5, 12), (7, 14)})
frozenset({(6, 12), (3, 8), (1, 13), (5, 10), (4, 9), (2, 11), (7, 14)})
frozenset({(6, 13), (3, 9), (2, 8), (1, 10), (4, 11), (5, 12), (7, 14)})
frozenset({(6, 12), (7, 14), (4, 9), (1, 8), (2, 11), (3, 10), (5, 13)})
frozenset({(6, 12), (3, 8), (1, 13), (5, 11), (4, 9), (2, 10), (7, 14)})
frozenset({(2, 9), (5, 10), (6, 13), (3, 12), (4, 11), (1, 8), (7, 14)})
frozenset({(6, 12), (3, 9), (4, 8), (7, 14), (1, 11), (2, 10), (5, 13)})
frozenset({(6, 12), (2, 9), (4, 8), (7, 14), (1, 11), (3, 10), (5, 13)})
frozenset({(3, 8), (6, 13), (1, 10), (4, 9), (2, 11), (5, 12), (7, 14)})
frozenset({(1, 12), (3, 8), (6, 13), (5, 11), (4, 9), (2, 10), (7, 14)})
frozenset({(6, 12), (2, 8), (3, 10), (7, 14), (4, 11), (1, 9), (5, 13)})
frozenset({(6, 12), (4, 10), (2, 8), (3, 11), (7, 14), (1, 9), (5, 13)})
frozenset({(2, 9), (4, 10), (3, 8), (6, 13), (1, 11), (5, 12), (7, 14)})
frozenset({(2, 9), (3, 8), (6, 13), (5, 11), (1, 10), (4, 12), (7, 14)})
frozenset({(3, 8), (6, 13), (5, 12), (2, 10), (4, 11), (1, 9), (7, 14)})
frozenset({(6, 13), (7, 14), (4, 9), (2, 10), (1, 8), (5, 12), (3, 11)})
frozenset({(4, 10), (6, 13), (3, 9), (2, 12), (5, 11), (1, 8), (7, 14)})
frozenset({(1, 12), (3, 8), (5, 10), (6, 13), (4, 9), (2, 11), (7, 14)})
frozenset({(6, 12), (2, 9), (7, 14), (4, 11), (1, 8), (3, 10), (5, 13)})
frozenset({(6, 12), (4, 10), (3, 8), (5, 11), (1, 9), (2, 13), (7, 14)})
frozenset({(6, 12), (3, 13), (5, 11), (4, 9), (2, 10), (1, 8), (7, 14)})
frozenset({(5, 10), (6, 13), (2, 12), (7, 14), (4, 9), (1, 8), (3, 11)})
frozenset({(3, 8), (6, 13), (5, 11), (2, 12), (1, 10), (4, 9), (7, 14)})
frozenset({(6, 12), (1, 13), (5, 11), (2, 8), (4, 9), (3, 10), (7, 14)})
frozenset({(6, 12), (2, 9), (3, 13), (5, 11), (1, 10), (4, 8), (7, 14)})
frozenset({(6, 13), (5, 11), (3, 12), (4, 9), (2, 10), (1, 8), (7, 14)})
frozenset({(6, 12), (4, 10), (1, 13), (3, 9), (5, 11), (2, 8), (7, 14)})
frozenset({(6, 12), (2, 9), (3, 13), (5, 10), (4, 8), (1, 11), (7, 14)})
frozenset({(6, 12), (2, 9), (5, 13), (1, 10), (4, 8), (3, 11), (7, 14)})
frozenset({(6, 12), (3, 9), (5, 11), (1, 10), (4, 8), (2, 13), (7, 14)})
frozenset({(6, 13), (5, 12), (4, 8), (7, 14), (2, 10), (1, 9), (3, 11)})
frozenset({(1, 12), (5, 10), (6, 13), (3, 9), (4, 8), (2, 11), (7, 14)})
frozenset({(6, 12), (3, 8), (2, 10), (7, 14), (4, 11), (1, 9), (5, 13)})
frozenset({(6, 12), (5, 10), (3, 9), (4, 13), (2, 8), (1, 11), (7, 14)})
frozenset({(6, 12), (2, 9), (3, 13), (4, 10), (5, 11), (1, 8), (7, 14)})
frozenset({(4, 10), (6, 13), (5, 12), (2, 8), (7, 14), (1, 9), (3, 11)})
frozenset({(6, 13), (5, 12), (2, 8), (3, 10), (4, 11), (1, 9), (7, 14)})
frozenset({(6, 12), (2, 9), (4, 10), (3, 8), (7, 14), (1, 11), (5, 13)})
frozenset({(1, 12), (6, 13), (3, 9), (5, 11), (4, 8), (2, 10), (7, 14)})
frozenset({(6, 12), (3, 9), (5, 11), (4, 13), (2, 10), (1, 8), (7, 14)})
frozenset({(6, 13), (3, 9), (5, 11), (2, 10), (1, 8), (4, 12), (7, 14)})
```

Demo [here](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=bVE7DsIwDBVrT-GNGApSEQNC4iSAEAIHLCEnStOhfE7CwgKH4jQ0LaWA6i3vYz_H14fN_d7I7XbPvB5Mnp1sSxp25Fd2zS5VgtMIigroqoGtMYc3E4o1iPEQ0AYMlTMdtqCdOZKk5BV-WG0cMLC0mEpqVHNDFk8upY1nI8qtZUeKoQejGAT6kCD-uusOZdDQ5C82DODEcTHg0mJsyzxXpRyXCOeqa2lz5DMnEBRfE8Kzyph88iFGkXXFGqrXCJMxxoXZzroL6WL1--8j1Md4AQ)

Comment: This does not generate every possible pairing. For example I do not see a (1, 2) pair anywhere in your output.

Comment: Why should it generate `(1, 2)` when it would leave the rest of the numbers unable to be split into pairs that satisfy the rule?

Comment: I misunderstood your definition of "legitimate pair", I see now that you only generate pairs which match OP's criteria. More importantly, this function produces many permutations of the same pairings, but the order of the pairs is not important according to the question. (With n=14, it outputs 7! * 144 pairings.)

Comment: Right. In that case one can use a set of frozensets instead to store the output.